# How to insert comma delimited values in one column in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle19c

I have a table by the name of personal_info and it contains id,name and phone_number as columns. So the following is table structure which I want to store data.

| id | name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ali | 03434444, 03454544, 0234334 |

So how to store data in phone_number column in comma delimited format and how to filter that column in where clause for example

```
Select * from personal_info where phone_number = 03454544 ;
```

And which datatype is suitable for phone_number column.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE` with the delimiters:

```sql
Select *
from   personal_info
where  ', ' || phone_number || ', ' LIKE '%, ' || '03454544' || ', %';
```

#### However

You should consider changing your data structure to store the phone numbers in a separate table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE phone_numbers (
  person_id    REFERENCES personal_info (id),
  phone_number VARCHAR2(12)
);
```

And then you can get the data using a `JOIN`

```sql
SELECT pi.*,
       pn.phone_number
FROM   personal_info pi
       INNER JOIN phone_numbers pn
       ON (pi.id = pn.person_id)
WHERE  pn.phone_number = '03434444'
```

or, if you want all the phone numbers:

```sql
SELECT pi.*,
       pn.phone_numbers
FROM   personal_info pi
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT person_id,
                LISTAGG(phone_number, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY phone_number)
                  AS phone_numbers
         FROM    phone_numbers
         GROUP BY person_id
         HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN phone_number = '03434444' THEN 1 END) > 0
       ) pn
       ON (pi.id = pn.person_id)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f25edc351daeff1082ccd78ac16c0fed)*

Answer (score 1):

Well, the real good practice would rather be to have another table PHONE with a 1xN association (for example a PHONE_ID primary key, and ID and PHONE columns.)

You may then have the result you want with a view based on your two tables and using the LISTAGG operator : https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Oracle_Database/Utilisation_de_fonctions/fonction_LISTAGG, but this will be much efficient to work with, especially if you want WHERE clauses based on your phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR2` is suitable for phone numbers.
You can get the values this way:

```
WITH personal_info AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Ali' AS NAME, '03434444, 03454544, 0234334' AS phone_number FROM dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, name, TRIM(regexp_substr(phone_number, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS phone_number
          FROM personal_info 
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (phone_number) - LENGTH(REPLACE(phone_number, ',' )) + 1)
 WHERE phone_number = '03454544';
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong data model, it isn't normalized. You should create a new table:

```
create table phones
  (id_phone     number constraint pk_phone primary key,
   id_person    number constraint fk_pho_per references person (id_person),
   phone_number varchar2(30) not null
  );
```

Then you'd store as many numbers as you want, one-by-one (row-by-row, that is).

---

If you want to do it *your way*, store it just like that:

```
insert into person (id, name, phone_number)
values (1, 'ali', '03434444, 03454544, 0234334');
```

One option of querying such data is using the `instr` function:

```
select * from person
where instr(phone_number, '03434444') > 0;
```

or `like`:

```
select * from person
where phone_number like '%'% || '03434444' || '%'
```

or split it into rows:

```
select * from person a
where '03434444' in (select regexp_substr(b.phone_number, '[^,]+', 1, level)
                     from person b
                     where b.id_person = a.id_person
                     connect by level <= regexp_count(b.phone_number, ',') + 1
                    )
```

---

I'd do it *my way*, i.e. with a new table that contains only phone numbers.

Comment: Your `LIKE` and `INSTR` queries will get the wrong values if someone stores the phone number `03434444567`.